# VLOOKUP function in VBA from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run this routine from my code but its giving me "Subscript out of range"

Do I have to use File Workbooks.Open etc ?

Herein the code

```
    Sub GetETAStatusURL()

Dim ETA_Status As String
Dim ETA_URL As String


ETA_Status = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(F7, Workbooks("excel_output.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$2:$C$5000"), 2, False)
ETA_URL = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(F7, Workbooks("excel_output.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$2:$C$5000"), 3, False)

Set Sheets("Invoice Template").Range("I23") = ETA_Status
Set Sheets("Invoice Template").Range("I24") = ETA_URL

'=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F7,'C:\Users\HP\Downloads\goRaqqami_1.1\excel\[excel_output.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$C$5000,2,FALSE),"")

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, you have to open the source workbook first. Also, unless it's a variable you haven't shown, you need to use `Range("F7")` (properly qualified with the relevant sheet), not just `F7`

Comment: I dont want to open the other excel file, because some other application is writing to it, I need to do the above function while the file is closed. is this possible ?

Comment: actually in excel vlookup function you dont have to open the source file ! so how in vba you have to ?

Comment: Formula <> VBA. If you can't open the source workbook, you need a formula, whether that is in a cell or evaluated in memory using `Evaluate`